# Transferring reputation between different SE sites

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty, stackexchange, multiple-accounts

As someone who has accounts on multiple Stack Exchange sites I am wondering if there is a means by which reputation between accounts can be transferred.

This may be useful, for example, to offer a bounty on a question one has asked in a subject that one has not built up much reputation. If one has built up enough reputation in a different subject on another SE site, then one has contributed to the Stack community in that subject, so it seems reasonable that they should be allowed to benefit from the extra perks that come with a higher reputation in other subjects.

If this is unreasonable, then perhaps one can gain a reputation point on one SE site at a cost of two reputation points in another (for example). This could avoid a mass transfer to more 'difficult' subjects.

What do people think about this?

Comment: This has been [asked on Meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346935/is-there-any-way-to-transfer-reputation-other-than-bounties).

Comment: That refers to transferring reputation between different users. I'm asking about transferring reputation between different accounts of the same user. Thanks.

Comment: Just two clarify: Are you talking about one user having two accounts on [math.se]? Or do you mean transferring reputation from one Stack Exchange site to another? (For example,  a user would transfer some reputation from their account on [mathematica.se] to their account on [math.se].)

Comment: If you mean the latter, there are some related posts on [meta.se]. For example: [Can I transfer my reputation between Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298218) (If you look at the linked question, you can find some other related posts.)

Comment: The latter i.e. one user transferring reputation between different subjects.

Comment: you can merge accounts. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous

Comment: Just so it's absolutely clear, giving yourself bounties from one account to the other is a very good way of moving reputation around and getting suspended (and then losing said reputation when the bounties are invalidated and the accounts are deleted). So pretty please, with sugar on top, to all the people who read this comment, don't do that.

Comment: I edited the post to make clear that you are asking about tranfering points between different sites and not between users on the same site.

Comment: Such a feature would be a change to Stack Exchange overall, so should be discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com) (or not even there, if it's felt to be a duplicate).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is more of a question for global meta than math meta - it deals with network-wide behavior rather than the specific workings of our individual site.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to transfer points from one SE site to another. However, there is the "association bonus" which at least allows for a start at 101 level instead of 1, and thus gives commenting and some other privileges right away.

Fundamentally, knowing one community does not say much about how one will fare in another. We can and do assume that a user with at least a couple of hundred points on another site is not a spammer and grant commenting privileges. But beyond that it's not really reasonable.